# How to return to the same scroll position when going back with infinite-scroll

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, infinite-scroll

When clicking on a specific Pokemon, the user can show details of the Pokemon. When the user clicks the back button to see all Pokemon, I want them to continue in the exact same scroll position/pokemon, where they first clicked. How to achieve this next.js using infinite scroll fetching api pagination?

solution for display data same last visited!

Comment: use recoil or useContext to save the current position scrollTop value before link to detail page. use useEffect in home page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to maintain the scroll position in Next.js with infinite scroll is to use React's state and the `window.scrollY` property. When a user clicks on a Pokemon, save the current scroll position in a state variable. Then, when the user navigates back, use the `useEffect` hook to restore the scroll position from the state.

For the infinite scroll, consider using the IntersectionObserver API. It can help you determine when you've reached the end of your list and need to fetch the next page of data.